# Java Scope of static variables and using variables in button action listeners

Tags: java, image, file, user-interface, scope

I am trying to create a program that prints out a picture with a text field of a string. I am confused as how to use the variable from an action listener outside of it to determine what the picture is.

The user of my program can press one of any five buttons at the top and it will return a random string. I have files saved in my project folder as that string.jpg, but I can't execute my code.

I know its something with scope because when I put an output line to print to the screen the imagestring it prints null and I get a null pointer exception. I had the same problem with setting the textbox but used a (probably?) bad workaround that I made work.

Yes, I am also aware that using public static variables is not good programming technique..I just cant figure out a way to make it work regardless, so I've come to you for help making it work and also possibly better programming technique.

Hopefully that is somewhat clear as to what I am trying to do. Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Answer (score 1):

`ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(imgStr);` is called before `imgStr` is initialized.

`imgStr` is assigned only when one of the buttons are clicked. You should give it an initial value.

I'm assuming you want to update the image of `label3` each time a button is clicked. Currently you only initialize that image once, based on the initial value of `imgStr`.

Comment: @Mike the listener changes the variable, but it also has to create a new ImageIcon and update label3 with it.

Comment: So I changed my "global" variables at the top of my class and then added the new iamgeicon and label3 to my mid action listener(see original post) but still nothing changes the picture. But the print line prints the correct string to the console. Sorry if I am ignorant..

Comment: @Mike You created a new instance of JLabel and assigned it to the label3 variable, but you didn't add it to the JFrame, which still holds the originial JLabel with the original image.